# CKEditor 4 TypeError: method 'removeStyle' undefined in onChange function in image upload

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

After updating the CKEditor to version 4.2 (from 4.1.2), or just updating the `image` plugin to 4.2, the editor keeps throwing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeStyle' of undefined
```

in the onChange function of the image dialog, when trying to upload an image to the server.

The upload still works, but it breaks the flow of the image upload, which is not very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Outcomment `onChange` in image plugin

After trying all sorts of stuff like changing what is returned by the server I found that the `onChange` function was actually just added in the newest version (see [**here**](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9794)).

> If I just commented out the whole `onChange` function in the source version of the [**image plugin**](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image), it fixed the problem.

I got the source version of the image plugin by downloading the source version of the whole editor here: **http://ckeditor.com/builder**

**NB**: Be ware! The source version acted very differently then the optimized one. Luckyli the image plugin did not.